# JDBC-backed Infinispan Cache on JBoss EAP/Wildfly

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

I am trying to create a JDBC-backed Infinispan cache on a JBoss EAP 7 (or Wildfly 10) server.  My `cache-container` definition in `standalone-full.xml` looks like this:

```
<cache-container name="SearchCacheContainer" default-cache="SearchCache" module="org.infinispan.cachestore.jdbc">
                <local-cache name="SearchCache">
                    <expiration max-idle="60000" interval="6000"/>
                    <transaction mode="FULL_XA"/>                   
                    <string-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanCacheDS" preload="true" passivation="false" purge="false">
                        <property name="databaseType">
                            postgres
                        </property>
                        <property name="createTableOnStart">
                            true
                        </property>
                        <string-keyed-table prefix="str_">  
                            <id-column name="id" type="VARCHAR2(200)"/>  
                            <data-column name="datum" type="BLOB"/>  
                            <timestamp-column name="version" type="NUMBER"/>  
                        </string-keyed-table> 
                    </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
```

I have also declared the necessary JDBC datasource in my server like this:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanCacheDS" pool-name="InfinispanCacheDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_infinispan_cache</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql-jdbc4</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>infinispan_cache</user-name>
                    <password>mypasswordhere</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

However, when I attempt to start my JBoss server, I see the following error and the server fails to start:

```
14:02:09,692 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=SearchCacheContainer/local-cache=SearchCache/store=string-jdbc' are not available:
    org.wildfly.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanCacheDS; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.
```

Can anyone explain what it is that I am doing wrong here?  The documentation on this particular feature seems pretty thin, so I'm sure there's something I'm missing, but can't figure out what.  Thanks!

Comment: Try set `data-source="InfinispanCacheDS"`

Comment: Looks like that's what it needed!  Although, it's not creating the tables on startup and it complains about the createTableOnStart property.  Any idea what the correct flag to use is?

Comment: In the xsd for infinispan 8.x (included in wildfly 10) https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/schemas/infinispan-cachestore-jdbc-config-8.0.xsd the property createTableOnStart doesn't exist for cache store element, there is createOnStart (create-on-start) attribute for table element, for now, I think is not posible to set this value in wildfly subsystem.

Comment: @Shadowman, do you still need a hand with this?

Answer (score -2):

You need to refer the below links[1], [2]:

[1]http://infinispan.org/docs/5.3.x/user_guide/user_guide.html

[2]http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e1433

Comment: Link #2 refers to Hibernate caching, and Link #1 is for configuring a standalone Infinispan instance.  Neither of those are what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for help in configuring a Wildfly/JBoss-managed Infinispan cache.